# Concatenating two DataFrames but only for common values in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes like this:

```
name    code phone_number 
Joe     BX13    03453
Bill    C308    321356
Donald  H314    34532
Mike    J4D6    2134

code vehicle
C308 Mercedes
H314 BMW
```

I would like to concatenate them but **only** for common values in a specific column so it would look like this:

```
name    code vehicle
Bill    C308 Mercedes
Donald  H314   BMW

df3=pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

looks promising but I don't know to specify that I only want the common values. What arguments should I put in the parenthesis?

Comment: You don't want the `phone_number` in the merged dataframe?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I would prefer not to have it if I have the choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Setting up your data

```
import pandas as pd
import io
t = '''
name,code,phone_number
Joe,BX13,3453
Bill,C308,321356
Donald,H314,34532
Mike,J4D6,2134'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))

t = '''
code,vehicle
C308,Mercedes
H314,BMW'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
```

Now you can merge the two dataframes with selected columns

```
df1[['name','code']].merge(df2, on='code', how='inner')
```

Out:

```
     name  code   vehicle
0    Bill  C308  Mercedes
1  Donald  H314       BMW
```

Comment: Apparently `df.merge` is the key. I was wrong by looking for `df.concat`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for pd.merge.

```
df2=pd.merge(df2,df1,on="code",how="inner").drop(columns="phone_number")
```

df1 is the data with `name    code phone_number`  columns
df2 is the data with `code vehicle`  columns